# Put symbols at a centered position before xymatrix (like for pmatrix)

Tags: lyx, diagrams, xymatrix

Sometimes it is necessary to do algebra with "diagrams/trees" ect. For my purposes the xymatrix environment is enough to write these diagrams. However the following expressen just looks wrong

```
\lambda \cdot \xymatrix{A \ar[d] \ar[r]& B \ar[d]\\ C \ar[r] & D }
```

because the "scalarproduct" is just not at the obvious position, which should be centered, relative to the absolut hight of the diagram.

Is there a way to use diagrams in equations, just like any other symbol, or maybe like pmatrix? Should be useable in the lyx editor without to much affort.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `\xymatrix ` in the `matrix` env or the `aligned` env? Those might vertically center it.

Comment: Can you give example code? Aligned doesn't seem to do the trick. regarding wraping in the matrix env, I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing it with `tiz-cd` or with the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node`:

The `pstricks` code requires compiling either with `latex -> dvips ->ps2pdf`, **or** directly with `pdflatex` if you load the `auto-pst-pdf` package and add the `--enable-write18 switch to the comiler (for MiKTeX) or`shell-escape`(for TeX Live and MacTeX), **or** directly with`xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pst-node} 

\begin{document}

\texttt{tikz-cd} solution: 
\[ λ\cdot\! \begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-Stealth}]
A \rar\dar &B \dar\\C\rar & D
\end{tikzcd}\]%

\texttt{psmatrix} solution: 
\[ \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=1.1cm, rowsep=0.7cm]
A &B \\C\ & D
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesep=3pt}
\ncline{1,1}{1,2}\ncline{1,1}{2,1}\nbput[npos=0.4]{λ\cdot{}}
\ncline{2,1}{2,2}\ncline{1,2}{2,2}
\end{psmatrix} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this leaves the question how to use tiz-cd in lyx.

Comment: I don't know Lyx, but it doesn't have an interface for the widely used tikz-cd? Other possibility: does it have an interface for `pstricks`? The `psmatrix` environment does the same job as `tikz-cd`.

Comment: seems like pstricks is supported. For tikz-cd, I don't know. Can you post the appropriate code using psmatrix in addition to your code for tikz-cd?

Comment: I've added the pstricks code.

Comment: Ok, but the code doesn't compile even without lyx. And changing compilers is too complicated for my taste.

Comment: Did you compile with `pdflatex`?

Comment: Yes. Error says: ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.17 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}
\ncline{1,1}{2,1}\nbput[npos=0.4]{λ\cdot{}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64107/discussion-between-bernard-and-mark-neuhaus).